# making the relationship through username and not id

Tags: php, mysql

So Lets say I have a user table and then a user_profile table. To connect the relationship there would be a user_id row within the user_profile table. Now when I'm building my applications I like to make my url show the username and not the user_id example:

```
http://www.example.com/username/profile
```

not:

```
http://www.example.com/user_id/profile
```

So what I find myself doing is getting the user_id through the username and then fetching the profile info which just adds an extra query for no reason. My questions is could I just make the relationship through the username which is just as unique as the id row in the users table. Or is this bad practice and I should stick with using user_id?

Comment: How are you building this application? There's nothing "bad" about having the username in the URL. Normally this is just a matter of properly decoding the URL parameters via routing. If your usernames are unique, you can fetch user by name directly, no ID required.

Comment: Joining by varchar although one has a ID at hand is indeed bad practice. The extra query to retrieve the user id is negligible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A much better idea would be to use the `user_id` to join the tables, but provide the username as a parameter.  Something like:

```
select p.*
  from users u
     , profiles p
 where u.id = p.user_id
   and u.username = ?
```